# Combination method to check integral

Tags: number-theory, combinations

Let $n,m$ is an positive integral, How can I prove $\frac {\prod _{i=0} ^{m^2-1} (n^{m^2}-n^i)} {{m^2}!}$ is integral?

Comment: If n is prime, then this is the number of basis of $M_m(F_n)$ without considering order.

Comment: John Omielan thank you

Comment: aleph0 I came up with this problem in that case, but it seems to hold n is not prime

Answer (score -1):

For positive integers $n,s$ let
$$f(n,s)=\prod_{i=0}^{s-1}(n^s-n^i)$$
We have to show $s!\mid f(n,s)$.
For every prime number $p$, let $\nu_p$ denote the $p$-adic valuation.
Then it's enough to show $\nu_p(s!)\leq\nu_p(f(n,s))$ for every $p$.
First, note that by [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) we have
\begin{align}
\nu_p(s!)
&=\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\left\lfloor\frac s{p^i}\right\rfloor\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac s{p^i}\\
&=\frac s{p-1}
\end{align}
hence $\nu_p(s!)\leq\lfloor s/(p-1)\rfloor$.

On the other hand, write
\begin{align}
f(n,s)
&=\prod_{i=0}^{s-1}(n^s-n^i)\\
&=\prod_{i=0}^{s-1}n^i(n^{s-i}-1)\\
&=n^{s(s-1)/2}\prod_{i=0}^{s-1}(n^{s-i}-1)\\
&=n^{s(s-1)/2}\prod_{j=1}^{s}(n^j-1)\\
\end{align}
Thus, if $p\mid n$, then:
\begin{align}
\nu_p(f(n,s))
&=\frac{s(s-1)}2\nu_p(n)\\
&\geq\frac{s(s-1)}2\\
&\geq\nu_p(s!)
\end{align}
where the last inequality is trivial for $1\leq s\leq 2$ while for $s\geq 3$ follows from:
\begin{align}
\frac{s(s-1)}2
&\geq s\\
&\geq\frac{s}{p-1}\\
&\geq\nu_p(s!)
\end{align}
If $p\nmid n$ and $q=\lfloor s/(p-1)\rfloor$, then
\begin{align}
\nu_p(f(n,s))
&=\sum_{j=1}^{s}\nu_p(n^j-1)\\
&\geq\sum_{k=1}^{q}\nu_p(n^{k(p-1)}-1)\\
&\geq\sum_{k=1}^{q}(1+\nu_p(k))\\
&\geq q\\
&\geq\nu_p(s!)
\end{align}

Comment: @downvoter: What's wrong with this proof?